# How to reduce the occupied RAM when you are dealing with a very sparse matrix in a single-cell Experiment in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm dealing with a very large and sparse dataset and the first issues I met occurred when I tried to use quickCluster  that reported me this error:

```
             'cannot allocate vector of size 156.6 Mb'
```

So, given that I cannot wait to change the RAM of my computer and I can't afford to use a cluster, I want to rely on some other strategies like some package that would allow me to handle sparse matrices. I'm thinking about sparseM but given that I don't know well this package I'd like to know how to shrink the ram allocation for these kind of matrices. Any suggestion will be very appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at: `Matrix::sparseMatrix`

Comment: or `slam::simple_sparse_array`

Comment: or `spray::spray`

Comment: Is this a publicly-available scRNA dataset @Firingam? I believe this question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ but if you post links to the dataset you will have a better chance of getting a solution

Comment: Very much appreciated!Thanks !